# Cache problem on a Yarn, Vite and Vue 3 app. I need to run yarn vite all the time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, yarnpkg, browser-cache

I have a problem with a Yarn/Vite/Vue3 app lately.
I've been working on this app on local environment for a few weeks, it has a git and I sometimes commit/push stuff.

These days every time I do a code modification, I need to run `yarn vite` or `yarn vite --force` for localhost to refresh correctly. It's super annoying.

I've tried `yarn cache clean`, but didn't work.
I've tried a trick where you change the version number on `package.json` but no luck.

I don't know if the problem comes from my browser or not.
**What methods can I try to fix this problem?**

Comment: Maybe clean the node folder and install everything from scratch.

Comment: yarn cache clean doesn't handle this. The cache inside your project can be relevant, /node_modules/.cache/ , you can clear it. It's unknown what's the cause and under which condition the problem occurs

Comment: without versions of node/yarn/vite, vite.config.js and package.json it's difficult to tell

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The issue seems to be over.. and I think it was GSAP related in some way.. Unsure. No need for further investigation.